# Serve isolinux.cfg from a network location

Tags: automated-install, iso, syslinux

Is it possible to configure a boot ISO to pull its menu over the network? I'd like to have an install iso which could be dynamically reconfigured to install different versions of my distribution.

I'd prefer HTTP but could live with a TFTP derivative if there is no other option.

Comment: Have you considered using pxelinux instead? It is a much more streamlined process, although you would need control  over the DHCP server scope 's options

Comment: Does a working PXE configuration present a menu of available images? Is it possible to edit the boot configuration of those images (eg, pass kernel boot parameters) without changing an ISO?

Comment: It does, if you configure it to. And yes, you can pass parameters to the loaded kernel. It is the same thing as ISOLINUX really, just customized for the PXE boot environment.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is already done i.e. by MS WDS/MDT/SCCM for the Windows world. There are also alternatives for the Windows and Linux world like [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html) that do exactly the same.

The idea instead of booting from an ISO it's to boot your client from the `net` (PXE). The client boots, it retrieves a Boot Manager (pxelinux) and its menu from the PXE server with all the booting/install options. Next the client decides which menu entry is the one to continue with. (I'm related to Serva development)